# Retrieve related objects in DetailView

Tags: django

In my DetailView, I want to get the object as per the kwargs in my url, plus also retrieve all the related (foreignkey) values of it.

I use:

```
queryset = Category.objects.select_related()
```

in the views, however, trying to access the related data using

```
{% for i in category.all %}
```

However, nothing shows in template when rendered.

I tried this in template

```
{% for i in category.toolkit_set %}
```

and it said the related object isn't iterable

I have in a jiffy, this my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ....
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ....

class Toolkit(models.Model);
    ....
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
```

I want to get the object of Category per the slug, plus retrieve all the associated related data in one db hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you have to use the same variable name to access the Category object as you have elsewhere in the template. Usually in a DetailView, unless you've explicitly changed it, the object name is just `object`.

Secondly, you have the two separate parts of accessing the related objects - `_set` and `all` - but you don't seem to have put them together.

So, it should be:

```
{% for toolkit in object.toolkit_set.all %}
```